# Handling conflicting cases pandas python

Tags: pandas

I have a data set where some rows are same but belong to different classes.
Example -

| index | Heading 1 | Heading 2 | Heading 1b | Heading 2b | Class/Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row -1 | a | b | c | d | 0 |
| row -2 | t | r | f | k | 0 |
| row -3 | m | u | p | l | 0 |
| row -4 | a | b | c | d | 1 |
| row -5 | m | u | p | l | 1 |
| row -6 | v | r | z | h | 0 |
| row -7 | z | q | y | o | 1 |
| row -8 | w | e | t | a | 1 |

row-1 and row-4 are same rows but with different class.
Similar case with row-3 and row-5
There are only two classes.

I want to make those rows to new class say for example -2
It will look like this:

| index | Heading 1 | Heading 2 | Heading 1b | Heading 2b | Class/Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row -1 | a | b | c | d | 2 |
| row -2 | t | r | f | k | 0 |
| row -3 | m | u | p | l | 2 |
| row -4 | a | b | c | d | 1 |
| row -5 | m | u | p | l | 2 |
| row -6 | v | r | z | h | 0 |
| row -7 | z | q | y | o | 1 |
| row -8 | w | e | t | a | 1 |

We can see those rows are mapped to 2. And the duplicates are also kept in the same order.
Previously, I use iloc and iterate. But it takes huge amount of time as the size of the data set is huge.
So, I converted into dictionary, it was fine and fast. But it requires bit of manipulation and more coding work.
I would like to know how can it be done in a simple way.

Comment: Why the order needs to be kept?

Comment: Because each row corresponds to a line.
After the process, I will add a column based on each rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your headings are pretty strange, since you have columns with the same names. I'll use columns Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 1b, Heading 2b.

First create a new column in your df marking duplicates rows :

```
df['Duped'] = df.duplicated(subset=['Heading 1', 'Heading 2', 'Heading 1b', 'Heading 2b'], keep=False).astype(int)
```

You now have a Duped column, with 1 if row is duped and 0 if not.

Then Modify Class/Target according to it :

```
df.loc[df['Duped'] == 1, 'Class/Target'] = 2
```

Then drop your intermediate Duped column :

```
df = df.drop(columns=['Duped'])
```

Comment: Thanks,             
Yea the columns are with different names heading-{1,2,3,4}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'], 'col2': [1,2,3,1,2,1], 'target': ['d', 'e', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'd']})

df2 = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
index_list = df2.groupby(list(df2)).apply(lambda x: tuple(x.index)).tolist()

index_new_category = [i[0] for i in index_list]
df.loc[index_new_category,'target'] = 2

index_to_drop = [i[1:] for i in index_list]
index_to_drop = list(sum(index_to_drop, ()))

df = df.drop(index_to_drop)
```